# How to switch columns of a text file?

Tags: matlab, text

I want to switch columns order in a bunch of text files and also remove some of the columns after switching. I'm trying to use `textscan` function in matlab. But I'm not sure how to do it.
This is a sample line in one of the text files (space is delimiter):

> 580.697942 1009.223279 3.012318 2 1 0 554 605 607 558 1004 996 1016 1021

For example, I want to bring the forth-to-sixth column to the first of the line:

> 2 1 0 580.697942 1009.223279 3.012318 554 605 607 558 1004 996 1016 1021

And maybe add some columns  (with value='0') afterwards.

I would appreciate some advice on how to do this.
Thanks

Comment: When you say "maybe add 0 columns" do you mean some randomized code that sometimes adds them and sometimes not? Please provide a **definitive** requirement and show us what you already tried along with wrong outputs or errors.

Comment: No, I meant to add some columns with value = '0'. For example, adding a new column to the left in witch every value is a constant '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `textscan`, I would recommend you to use the `dlmread` function.

```
out = dlmread( 'mytextfile.txt' );
```

The output is an array, by using MATLAB basic commands you will be able to change columns as you wish.